# Turn off Order Status updates within Order Notes using WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-hook

I am looking to switch off all the order status updates that get used by default on every Woocommerce order ***but*** still be able to use manual notes that I add myself whether public or private notes.

Is this possible perhaps via a hook or something similar?

This is how the order notes look at the moment:

[image]

Comment: If you see [class-wc-order.php status_transition()](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-order.php#L374) method there is no option to stop order status transit message logging. and also there is no filter exclude some message from displaying. So you have to delete those message from database, it can be manual or automated.

Comment: @RaunakGupta you're right, however we can use some tricks to do so. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

Actually there isn't any message specific hook for order notes. Instead you can use `woocommerce_order_status_changed` action hook which is fired just after changing the order status, to get translated value of order note. In the next step you should use `woocommerce_new_order_note_data` filter hook in  the function, which is hooked to the `woocommerce_order_status_changed` action, to compare and unset the order note in case of status change.

The final code would be something like this:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'remove_order_status_change_notes', 10, 3);
function remove_order_status_change_notes($order_id, $status_from, $status_to)
{
    $transition_note = sprintf( __( 'Order status changed from %1$s to %2$s.', 'woocommerce' ), wc_get_order_status_name($status_from), wc_get_order_status_name($status_to) );
    add_filter('woocommerce_new_order_note_data', function ($args) use ($transition_note)
    {
        if ($args['comment_content'] ===  $transition_note) {
            return [];
        } else {
            return $args;
        }
    });
}
```

**Tested and it's working**